Prove that the only natural value of $g$ that makes $8g+4p^2-4p+1$ ($p\in\mathbb{N}$) a perfect square is $g=p$
This problem came up while I was working on a larger problem and I've looked at a few different ways of solving it, the main approach being mathematical induction; however, I've been unable to prove the inductive step: $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ where $P(n)$ is defined as: if $g\in \mathbb{N}$, then $8g+4n^2-4n+1$ is a perfect square iff $g=n$. I've also tried assuming that $g$ is some quadratic in terms of $p$ and solving for the constants, but again I got lost.
I feel like I'm missing some knowledge that will help me solve the problem so any suggestions or solutions will be helpful.
Note I'm using $0\notin \mathbb{N}$

A counterexample is $g=1$ and $p=0$.

I should have specified that I'm using $0\notin \mathbb{N}$ thank you though

What about $g=3,p=1$?

Thank you. I realized that I made an error in my question

It seems that there is a typo in the question, because the claim is just not true.

Thanks I didn't catch that other reference to it

@DietrichBurde yeah, I realized afterwards that my question was not equivalent to the question I intended to ask: for what values of $g$ is $\frac{-(2g-1)+\sqrt{8g+4p^2-4p+1}}{2}\in \mathbb{N}$ where $g,p\in\mathbb{N}$

There are infinitely many counterexamples, e.g. consider $g=2p+1$ and $p\in\mathbb N$, then
$$8g+4p^2-4p+1=4p^2+12p+9=(2p+3)^2.$$

This only shows one direction, but hopefully it will be able to help you:
If $g=0$ then $8g+4p^{2}-4p+1=4p^{2}-4p+1$ and if $g=p$ then $8g+4p^{2}-4p+1=4p^{2}+4p+1$. In either case we can simply take $p\in\mathbb{Z}$.
$4p^{2}-4p+1=\left(1-2p\right)^{2}$
$4p^{2}+4p+1=\left(1+2p\right)^{2}$,
so for $g\in\{0,p\}$ we obtain perfect squares.
